# Как сделать мгновенное отображение шрифта при открытии скрытого блока?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок со свойством `display: none`, в котором для текста используется нестандартный шрифт.
 При отображении этого блока - `display: block`, текст нужным шрифтов отображается через какие-то время.
 Как сделать отображение текста нужным шрифтом сразу после показа блока?
 Какие есть способы предварительной загрузки шрифтов?

Comment: Может использовать его где-то еще, кроме скрытого блока?

Comment: Этот шрифт используется только для заголовка скрытого блока. Использование где-то еще решило бы проблему, но в моем случае не подходит.

Comment: Может вместо display:none; попробовать использовать стиль position:absolute; visibility: hidden; а для показа position:static;
visibility: visible;.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вы подключаете шрифт? Как вы показываете модальное окно?
Как выглядит ваш код? Воспроизводима ли ваша ошибка?

Вот рабочий вариант, подключайте шрифт внутри html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

```css
#font1 {
  font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
}

#font2 {
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
}
```

```html
 <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">

<a href=#font1 class=fancybox>font1</a>
<a href=#font2 class=fancybox>font2</a>
<div id=font1 style="display:none">font1</div>
<div id=font2 style="display:none">font2</div>
```

Либо как было написано выше в комментариях - вызовите шрифт до открытия модального окна, например в пустом диве